# Enable Request File link in SharePoint Site using Set-SPOSite -RequestFilesLinkEnabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

The documentation for Set-SPOSite has the argument for RequestFilesLinkEnabled and it can be passed without returning an error but does not provide the RequestFilesLink option on the Sharepoint site. I have enabled "anyone links" for the site I'm testing this on. Is the configuration option left for when this feature was briefly introduced but removed a few years ago?

I can use the Request File feature in OneDrive for business but I would prefer the landing page not show the account owner's name above the title that you provide. Does anyone have a workaround for removing the account owner display name?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that while the Set-SPOSite has an argument for RequestFilesLinkEnabled it a feature that is only available in OneDrive for Business and not available in SharePoint Document libraries.